# Testing Hadoop to Teradata flow

Tags: hadoop, testing, teradata

I would like to test a flow between an hadoop datalake and teradata tables. The thing is that I am new to these technologies.
The data lake is my data source for the datawarehouse I have on teradata.
I read about QuerySurge but I'd like to know if it is possible to create my own scripts to test the flows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Teradata offers connectors for Cloudera ([link](http://www.cloudera.com/content/www/en-us/downloads/connectors/sqoop/teradata/1-2c5.html)) and Hortonworks ([link](http://hortonworks.com/hdp/addons/)) which facilitate moving data between the platforms.

QueryGrid is an offering from Teradata that allows you to create "linked servers" on your Teradata platform. Using these "linked servers" you are able to query data on a Hadoop platform from Teradata. Currently, these types of workloads are intended to be low concurrency. That landscape is evolving fairly quickly and concurrency rates may increase as the technologies evolve and mature.

Answer (score -1):

Feel free to use QuerySurge.

I'm working on Querysurge from last 5 years to test and validate the data from different sources.

it's basically automation of custom SQL Scripts.

[QuerySurge](http://www.querysurge.com/)